# How can I set env variables so that KDE recognizes them?

Tags: kde, environment-variables, kwin

I need to set some environment variables such as the XDG spec ones, before KDE starts in such a way that kwin and any apps run from KDE will inherit them. Where could I do this, and how?

Comment: Check out: https://userbase.kde.org/Session_Environment_Variables

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put them in a `.sh` file in `~/.kde/env/` (possibly `~/.kde4/env/` or similar; varies by distribution).

Comment: I've been trying that, but my XDG configs are still showing up in `~/.config` such as `~/.config/akonadi`, here's [the script](https://github.com/xenoterracide/dot_etc/blob/master/env)that I copied to that directory. I actually gave this answer first, but deleted it when I realized it wasn't working

Comment: @xenoterracide: The scripts must be named `*.sh`.

Comment: well that's very un-unix-y gotcha's for the lose

Comment: tested, and renaming to use `.sh` works, mind adding that as part of the answer?

Answer (score 14):

For Plasma 5 it's

> ~/.config/plasma-workspace/env/

Comment: souce: https://userbase.kde.org/Session_Environment_Variables