# When not started from a terminal, Emacs does NOT pick up the SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable

Tags: shell, environment-variables, emacs

When I don't start it from a terminal, Emacs 24.5.1 (compiled from source) doesn't pick up my environment variables. In particular, to "import" the environment variables from shell, I have in my `.emacs`

```
(setq exec-path-from-shell-variables
      (quote ("PATH" "MANPATH" "INFOPATH" "C_INCLUDE_PATH" "CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH"
              "LIBRARY_PATH" "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" "SSH_AUTH_SOCK")))
(exec-path-from-shell-initialize)
```

and to provide my unlocked private key to `ssh` using GNOME Keyring's "`ssh-agent`" (aka `gnome-keyring-daemon`) I have in my `.bashrc` (my user shell is `bash`)

```
if [ -n "$DESKTOP_SESSION" ];then
    eval $(gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=ssh)
    export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
fi
```

But upon doing any remote-related task (e.g., `push` or `pull`) in Magit I get the error

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

in the `*magit-process*` buffer, which means that Emacs does not see my unlocked private key and, hence, that Emacs is not using the socket provided by `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, because the same remote-related `git` commands run without any problems in a terminal.

I've checked in `eshell` and `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` has the same value in Emacs as it does in an outside terminal with `bash`. Also, when I start Emacs from a terminal (in X or a TTY), all the environment variables are picked up and there are no problems. I know when run in a terminal, Emacs inherits the environment variables from the shell. My question is why aren't my environment variables (which are apparently "imported" correctly into Emacs by `exec-path-from-shell-variables`) used by Emacs when I don't start it from a terminal? The same setup has been working on my other machine for several years with Emacs 24.3, but I doubt the culprit could be the newer Emacs version.

Edit: My operating system is Trisquel 7.0 which is based on Ubuntu 14.04 GNU/Linux. I usually use LXDE, but the problem is there with other desktop environments too. Outside a terminal I start Emacs by pressing `Alt+F2` (Run) and entering `emacs`. In a terminal I start Emacs by entering `emacs`. My environment variables are set in `~/.bashrc`. I am aware of the intricacies of login and non-login shells (interactive or not) and I've checked that my `~/.bashrc` is run regardless of how I log in (e.g., in X to a desktop environment or window manager, in a TTY, or through `ssh`).

Comment: Where are you setting your environment variables, and how do you start Emacs? What operating system are you using (if Linux, what distribution), with what desktop environment if Linux or other Unix?

Comment: @Gilles I've edited my question and added extra information that may help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Emacs but about the environment that Emacs is running in. It would be on-topic on [unix.se].

Comment: What do you get when you evaluate `(getenv "SSH_AUTH_SOCK")` inside of Emacs?  Does it help if you manually set it with `(setenv ...)`?

Comment: @rekado `(getenv "SSH_AUTH_SOCK")` in an Emacs session started "from a menu" or from a terminal shows the same socket as `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` does in a terminal (outside Emacs) in X, just like `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` does in Emac's `eshell`. Using `(setenv ...)` manually didn't help. (That's what `exec-path-from-shell-variables` is doing, essentially.)

Answer (score 3):

> My environment variables are set in `~/.bashrc`.

There's your problem. Then your environment variables are only set in applications that you start from a terminal, they are not set in applications started from a GUI menu.

> I am aware of the intricacies of login and non-login shells (interactive or not) and I've checked that my `~/.bashrc` is run regardless of how I log in (e.g., in X to a desktop environment or window manager, in a TTY, or through ssh).

Evidently you are *not* aware of the intricacies of login and non-login shells. Your `.bashrc` is not run at all when you log in. It's run when you start an interactive shell.

The solution is to set your variables where they should be set, i.e. in `~/.pam_environment` or `~/.profile` (which is read by sessions invoked by some display managers such as GDM) or `~/.xsessionrc` (which is read by sessions invoked by some display managers such as Lightdm).

See [Alternative to .bashrc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc), [Correctly setting environment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4621/correctly-setting-environment), [What's the best distro/shell-agnostic way to set environment variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88201/whats-the-best-distro-shell-agnostic-way-to-set-environment-variables), [How do I set the PATH or other environment variables so that X apps can access it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81243/how-do-i-set-the-path-or-other-environment-variables-so-that-x-apps-can-access-i), [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell) and many more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. (I've read all of the material you've linked to in the past and learned much from your detailed answers in particular.) When I said "... my `~/.bashrc` is run regardless of how I log in ..." I didn't mean it is run necessarily directly. My `~/.profile` runs my `~/.bashrc`. In any case, I'll take this question somewhere else.

Comment: @Omid I've flagged the question for migration. Please don't repost. Depending on your display manager (i.e. the program where you log in), `.profile` may or may not be read — you may need to use `.xsessionrc` or some other file instead. You should not load `.bashrc` unconditionally from `.profile`, only if the shell is interactive.