# $HOME/bin dir is not on the $PATH

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian, path, profile

In my `~/.profile` I have a last block which should load my personal `bin/ directory` like this:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

But it is seemingly not loaded:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Why is this not working? (My shell is bash.)

**Edit for Tigger**

```
echo $0 => bash

echo $HOME => /home/student

whoami => student

less /etc/*-release => 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Comment: For background on this part of `.profile`, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/284640/ .

Comment: Which shell is this?

Comment: I assume the directory exists, right?

Comment: @njsg it is bash

Comment: Possibly something else is resetting your PATH variable after this is run. You can verify by using the `-x` flag passed to bash and seeing where the PATH is reset. Also, you need to `export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` to provide it to subsequent processes.

Comment: Also you should use the bashrc file if you only need this loaded for interactive sessions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the top of `~/.profile`:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.
```

So (if you are using `bash` as your shell) I'm guessing either `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` is on your system. Select one and edit it to include:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

Then save and `source ~/.bash_login` or logout and log back in.

**Edit**:

You say that both `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_login` are both missing from your `$HOME`. I think we need confirm a few things. Please post the results of the following in your original question:

```
echo $0
echo $HOME
whoami
less /etc/*-release
```

**Edit 2**:

Personally, I do not know why `~/.profile` is not being included in your case based on the information provided and documentation. While testing I did notice that my `~/.profile` is scanned when I `ssh` in but not when I launch a new terminal.

But, there is a simple solution to allow `$HOME/bin` to be included in your interactive shell. Edit (create if not present) `~/.bashrc` and add the following line to it:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

Save, logout and log back in, or `source ~/.bashrc`.

The `export` line could be expanded to check that `$HOME/bin` exists if you like with:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ]
then
    export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
fi
```

Why `~/.bashrc` instead of another file? Personally preference and seems to be more reliable too.

Comment: Although, since the questioner did not specify which shell, there is also the possibility that one is not using the Bourne Again shell at all.    Certainly other people with this same question might not be.

Comment: @JdeBP : added clarification to answer. Assumed as a Debian user they had not changed their default interactive shell, but I guess they could have.

Comment: I don't have any of the `~/.bash_profile` nor `~/.bash_login`. At my `~` there are only `.bash_history` and `.bash_logout` (and of course the `.profile`).

Comment: @Tigger updated!

Comment: @student : Made another update. Really at a loss as to what is going on. Pretty interested to hear if you find out why `~/.profile` is being skipped.

Answer (score 6):

The [rules for in-sourcing shell startup files are complex](https://s0.cyberciti.org/uploads/cms/2015/01/BashStartupfiles.jpg).
It's likely that with your setup, `.profile` is not getting included when you open up a new terminal within an X session (try putting an `echo .profile` inside of `.profile` and see if the message shows up when you start a shell).

```
.  "$HOME/.profile"
```

should reload the profile manually.

Logging in and out of X should also cause `.profile` to load.

Alternatively, you can do `. $HOME/.profile` from `.bashrc` (while using a variable-based guard to prevent double inclusion) to make sure `.profile` is always included whenever you start a shell.

(You shouldn't need to `export PATH` as `PATH` is already an exported variable and modifying its value won't change its `export` status.)

Comment: sourcing .profile from .bashrc ! in most of cases .profile contains ` . .bashrc` , this won't go trought an infinite loop ?!

Comment: @youness I'm doing both and I'm using include guards (`[ -z "$has___profile" ] || return;  has__profile=1`) so I get no infinite loops  and both `.profile` and `.bashrc` (only if BASH_VERSION is defined) no matter how I got there.

Comment: i got it ! my bad english pushed me to ask this uneeded question ,  ( puting code for explaination is better than literal expression ) . thanks for your time :-)

Comment: A simple `bash -l` will load `.profile` (unless some odd configuration). Also, the PATH should be correctly set when the user logs in. That means in the "display manager" (dm) in use: gnome, KDE, xfce, lxde, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get `.profile` loaded all you need is to start a login shell:

```
$ bash -l
```

That should be enough for a running session. You can compare the PATH before and after a login bash has been started to confirm the difference.

For a more permanent solution you need that a login shell to be started at some point before your terminal (console) starts. The login as an specific user happens on some dm (display manager) (gnome,kde,xfce,lxde, etc). It should be the job of any of them to change the environment variable PATH to match your needs.

For example, for xfce, the solution is to change `xinitrc`:

```
$ cat >"$HOME/.config/xfce4/xinitrc" <<-\_EOT_
#!/bin/sh

# Ensure programs in ~/bin are available for the X session.
p="$HOME/bin";
[ "$p" != "${PATH%%:*}" ] && export PATH=$p:$PATH
_EOT_
cat "/etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc" | tail -n+2 >> "$HOME/.config/xfce4/xinitrc"
```

For gnome, it seems that [the file to change](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81274/232326) is `~/.pam_environment`.

And for KDE, [follow this guide](https://userbase.kde.org/Session_Environment_Variables/en), to create the file, you may use this code:

```
$ file='$HOME/.config/plasma-workspace/env/path.sh'
$ code='export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH'
$ echo "$code" >> "$file"
```